# Related to ipad Screen

Tags: ipad

Thanks in advance.
   While executing my app in iPad am getting the starting screen like this 1/4 of the iPad screen. (here I am unable to post the screen)

Comment: But you could post the relevant code

Comment: I have created the app for both iphone and ipad and the starting nib only displaying like that i statically created the nib not programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try go run an iPhone app on the iPad.

the app will still work, but the ipad screen is much bigger, so it is only displayed on 1/4th of the screen (nicely in the middle)

You can fullscreen the app by pressing the x2 in the bottom right corner.

This is what this will look like, before and after:
http://static.arstechnica.com/wifi-ipad-review/double-size-iphone-apps.jpg

If you want to create an app that shows fullscreen on an Ipad and Iphone, you should make it universal.
see here for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

edit:
if you only have issues with the splash screen, then you need a new default.png
as explained here: http://phunkwerk.posterous.com/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images-aka-defa

```
Default-Portrait.png *  768w x 1004h
Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png  768w x 1004h
Default-Landscape.png **    1024w x 748h
Default-LandscapeLeft.png   1024w x 748h
Default-LandscapeRight.png  1024w x 748h
Default.png     Not recommended
```

Comment: Thank u for ur response. Yes i know by pressing x2 we will get the full screen. But i mean by 1/4 of image is not like the image u posted.That is if the ipad screen resolution is 768x1024 in that it showing only 1/4th part but the next screen it is showing normally means 768x1024.

Comment: did you create a Default.png with the full resolution? I added this to my answer.

Comment: The problem is not with Splash screen , with homescreen